# VBA Rename spreadsheet based on specific cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to rename my spreadsheet based on specific cell value. 
For example my cell A1 for the different spreadsheet are as follow:

- Spreadsheet 1: Invoice 120894, Att.:LVM & TPM , ATM Username
- Spreadsheet 2: Invoice 120896, Att: TAM TAM, ATM Username

I'd like to give my spreadsheet the name in cell A1 with for instance LVM & TPM and TAM TAM.

Could someone please help?

I have found a code which would help renaming but I am not sure how to ignore the values and special characters around :

```
   Sub RenameSheet()

 'VARIABLES DECLARATION
  Dim rs As Worksheet
  Dim new_name As String, tmp_new_name As String
  Dim counter As Integer: counter = 0
  Dim counter1 As Integer: counter1 = 1
  Dim allNames As Object

  'CODE
  Set allNames = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

  For Each rs In Sheets
'FIRST, LET'S PARSE THE NAME "LAST NAME" + ", " + "NAME INITIAL" + "."
new_name = Split(rs.Range("A1"), " ")(1) 
'CHECK IF IT EXISTS
If allNames.Exists(new_name) Then
    'ADD A COUNTER "(N)" UNTIL IT DOESN'T EXIST ANYMORE
    tmp_new_name = new_name
    Do While allNames.Exists(tmp_new_name) <> False
        tmp_new_name = new_name & " (" & counter1 & ")"
        counter1 = counter1 + 1
    Loop
    counter1 = 1
    new_name = tmp_new_name
End If
'RENAME
rs.Name = new_name
counter = counter + 1
'KEEP THE NAME STORED IN MEMORY (INTO THE DICTIONARY)
allNames.Add rs.Name, counter
Next rs
End Sub
```

Thank you !

Comment: Your real question is simply "How can I extract `LVM & TPM` from `Invoice 120894, Att.:LVM & TPM , ATM Username` ?" - I recommended looking at `InStr()` function, finding the ":" and the ","

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good example. With string Hack&Slash you always have to keep in mind the formatting of the strings, and sometimes have to play around with it to get it just right.

```
Private Sub this()
    Dim this$: this = "Invoice 120894, Att.:LVM & TPM , ATM Username"
    this = Mid(this, InStr(1, this, ":") + 1, Len(this) - InStrRev(this, ",") - 3)
    Debug.Print ; this
End Sub
```

b/c i get the feeling you're super new to this, I figure id expand on my example so that you can make sense of what it is doing

```
Private Sub this()
    Dim this$: this = "Invoice 120894, Att.:LVM & TPM , ATM Username"
    '                  123456789012314567890123456789012345678901234
    this = Trim(this)
        'String to use       starting point           Length of extracted string
    this = Mid(this, InStr(1, this, ":") + 1, Len(this) - InStrRev(this, ",") - 3)
    '                start at position 21          to position 29
    Debug.Print ; this
End Sub
```

See if this helps - you need to be able to tell the compiler where to find the value you want to manipulate.

```
Private Sub this()
    Dim this$
    this = ThisWorkbook.worksheets("yourworksheetname").Range("A1").Value
    this = Mid(this, InStr(1, this, ":") + 1, Len(this) - InStrRev(this, ",") - 3)
    Debug.Print ; this
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanx @Doug Coats the challenge is that I have at least 10 spreasheet in workbook with different Invoice number and names. Is there a way to avoid having to retype the different invoice name in :           Dim this$: this = "Invoice 120894, Att.:LVM & TPM , ATM Username"

Comment: Yes. It depends on how you are searching through your files. If you're looping through rows, just reference the cell. If you're using worksheet functions its completely different approach. Basically, however you're referencing the cell, you can replace "this" with that cell reference.

Comment: I am indeed very new to this. I appreciate the detailed explanation.  I have referenced the cell as this= Range("A1") but it does not seem to work. Could you please advise?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick sub routine to extract the details you need from the strings you start with, providing they're always in the same format, I'm sorry I can't elaborate more at this time since I'm leaving work, I hope you can apply it to your code.

```
Sub f()

Dim x As String
Dim n As String

    x = "Invoice 120894, Att.:LVM & TPM , ATM Username"
    n = Left(x, Len(x) - InStr(1, x, ","))
    n = Trim(Right(n, Len(n) - InStr(1, n, ":")))

    MsgBox n

End Sub
```

Comment: @Thnx jamheadhart would you know how I could apply it in my code so the spreadsheet would be renamed? Sorry im a new to VBA

Comment: `Sheets("Sheet Name").name = n`